# Inno Setup Script - running exe before installing

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

I wanna run an application before installing and I'm using this code on Inno Setup Script(Pascal):

```
function InitializeSetup():boolean;
var
  ResultCode: integer;
begin

 // Launch Notepad and wait for it to terminate
 if ExecAsOriginalUser('{src}\MyFolder\Injector.exe', '', '', SW_SHOW, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode) then
 begin
// handle success if necessary; ResultCode contains the exit code
 end
 else begin
   // handle failure if necessary; ResultCode contains the error code
 end;

 // Proceed Setup
  Result := True;

end;
```

When I'm using "{win}\notepad.exe", It works but when I use "{src}\MyFolder\Injector.exe", Setup doesn't open my program and continues install.

Note : Injector has app.manifest which has 'requireAdministrator'. However this application should be run as administrator.

So what's wrong?

Comment: I copy/pasted my app to Desktop and when I use this : 'C:\Users\Oceanjack\Desktop\Injector.exe', it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the `ExpandConstant` function when using values such as `{src}` in code.

However, `InitializeSetup` is also too early to run installation tasks.  You should move this code into `CurStepChanged(ssInstall)`.

Also, if it requires admin permissions it must be run with `Exec`, not `ExecAsOriginalUser`.

Comment: Note that the preferred place to run before-install tasks is in the `PrepareToInstall` event function.  This also gracefully handles errors and requests to reboot before the main installation begins.

Answer (score 1):

This May work for you... I believe that  this problem is because of spaces in the entire path..that should overcome with double quoting the path...

```
Exec('cmd.exe','/c "'+ExpandConstant('{src}\MyFolder\Injector.exe')+'"', '',SW_SHOW,ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode);
```

cheers..